# How can I make players not use the PvP flag on their regions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-worldguard

I use WorldGuard for making regions. I allow players to create their own regions, but I don't want them to be able to ban PvP on their regions. Is it possible to ban one, single flag?